# ng-src in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We can use image src with `src` and `ng-src` in angular js

```
 <img src="theme/image.png" alt="Image"/>
```

AND

```
<img ng-src="theme/image.png" alt="Image"/>
```

I do not feel any difference between them in showing image.is there any difference? I have a project with views are loading from an external site,do i need to change every `src` to `ng-src`?does it create any performance issue when i try to load large number of images?

Comment: Just use ng-* scopes when your values are scope statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me quote

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 2):

If the URL of the image is static, you can use `src` attribute on image.

```
<img src="theme/image.png" alt="Image"/>
```

When the URL of image is dynamic and need to set from `Controller`, use `ng-src`. **any string which can contain {{}} markup**

```
<img ng-src="{{theme}}/image.png" alt="Image"/>
//   ^^^     ^^^^^^^^^
```

[**DOCS**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.